# Перестала работать авторизация через соц.сети на 1C-Bitrix. Что делать?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, битрикс

Коллеги добрый день!
В один неприятный момент перестала работать авторизация пользователя через VK и FB.
Используется стандартный битриксовый функционал \bitrix\modules\socialservices\classes\general\vkontakte.php
Через Твиттер прекрасно входит.
У нас VDS
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Comment: Что говорит поддержка битрикса? Какие ошибки? Хоть что-то дайте.

Comment: ?auth_service_id=VKontakte&auth_service_error=1, поддержку еще не мучил, версия Битрикса 17.0.15

Comment: ну а в консоли есть ошибки? что гуглится по этому поводу. если функционал стандартный надо дергать поддержку битрикса.

Comment: гуглится проблема с подстановкой фейкового емэйла пользователю, но не помогло

Comment: тогда пишите в поддержку. пусть объясняют.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для тех, кто придет из поиска, дублирую ответ разработчика bitrix с https://toster.ru/q/517743:

Как не парадоксально звучит, но нужно обновиться.
Дело в том, что Вконтакте и Facebook в одностороннем порядке изменяют свое API. Например FB изменил протокол, а VK теперь явно требует указывать номер версии.

Авторизация ВК исправлена в версии 17.5.4 (обновления будет достаточно)
Авторизация FB исправлена в версии 17.5.3 (помимо обновления, нужно еще и настройки в кабинете разработчика Facebook изменить)

Comment: Да прямо скажем, первое, что нужно делать, когда "внезапно поломался функционал" -- обновиться.